# D'Alembert Formula nonhomogenous bounday condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> I just need help converting the nonhomogeneous boundary condition into a homogenous boundary condition using change of variables $u=v+w$.

Since D'Alembert formula is for the infinite domain $-\infty<x<\infty$ and my problem is for a semi-infinite domain $0<x<\infty$ then I know I must adjust the problem.

I have this wave equation problem $$u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0 \quad 0<x<\infty, \ t>0$$$$u(0,t)=t^2, \quad t>0$$ $$u(x,0)=x^2, \quad 0\le x\le\infty$$ $$u_t(x,0)=6x, \quad 0\le x<\infty$$ which I need help changing the boundary condition into a homogenous boundary condition.

---

For instance, I see that for the wave equation $$u_{tt}-u_{xx}=-1 \quad -\infty<x<\infty, \ t>0$$$$u(x,0)=x^2, \quad u_t(x,0)=1$$ when substituted to a homogenous equation we have that $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-\frac{t^2}{2}$ which I am not sure how it was obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function $w$ that satisfies the PDE and has $w(0,t)=t^2$. This is a quadratic polynomial. Try to fit a quadratic polynomial: 
$$w(x,t)=Ax^2+t^2$$
To satisfy $w_{xx}=w_{tt}$, you need $A=1$. So, $w(x,t)=x^2+t^2$ should be used.

And now the problem for $v=u-w$ becomes pretty simple: $w(0,t)=0$, $w(x,0)=0$,  $w_t(x,0)=6x$ (in general, the initial values need to be extended as an odd function, but since $6x$ is odd, it's just $6x$).

Comment: Thank you very much again! It is much clearer to me now.